# Create a custom target that call subproject custom targets

Tags: cmake, subproject

I've many sub-folders

```
home
|
|-library1
|-library2
|
|-libraryn
```

I have a main `CMakeLists.txt` in home folder, and a CMakeLists.txt for every subfolder.

In every subproject I've a custom target that I use to compile documentation

```
# in library1/CMakelists.txt
find_package (Doxygen)
if (DOXYGEN_FOUND)
  set (Doxygen_Dir ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/export/${library1_Version}/doc)
  # Copy images folder
  file (GLOB IMAGES_SRC "images/*")
  file (COPY ${IMAGES_SRC} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/images)
  configure_file (${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Doxyfile ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile @ONLY)
  add_custom_target (library1_doc
    ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
    COMMENT "Generating doxygen documentation" VERBATIM
  )
else (DOXYGEN_FOUND)
  message (STATUS "Doxygen must be installed in order to compile doc")
endif (DOXYGEN_FOUND)

# in libraryn/CMakelists.txt
find_package (Doxygen)
if (DOXYGEN_FOUND)
  set (Doxygen_Dir ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/export/${library1_Version}/doc)
  # Copy images folder
  file (GLOB IMAGES_SRC "images/*")
  file (COPY ${IMAGES_SRC} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/images)
  configure_file (${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Doxyfile ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile @ONLY)
  add_custom_target (libraryn_doc
    ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
    COMMENT "Generating doxygen documentation" VERBATIM
  )
else (DOXYGEN_FOUND)
  message (STATUS "Doxygen must be installed in order to compile doc")
endif (DOXYGEN_FOUND)
```

As you see, in every subproject I create a `libraryn_doc` target.

This is the main CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)

### Versions ###
# This exports the library version
set (library1_Version 0.0)

### Projects ###
add_subdirectory (library1)
add_subdirectory (library2)
add_subdirectory (library3)
add_subdirectory (library4)

### Project dependencies ###
add_dependencies (librrary4 library1)

### Project documentation ###
add_custom_target(doc
  DEPENDS library1 library2 library3 library4
  )
```

I want to modify the `doc` target of main CMakelists.txt in order to execute all libraryn_doc custom targets, so I can build documentation simply by using `make doc` instead of `make library1_doc; ... make libraryn_doc`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply modify the dependencies of your `doc` target like this:

```
add_custom_target(doc
    DEPENDS library1_doc library2_doc library3_doc library4_doc)
```